# Adobe PDF Ifilter 11 and 9 on Win 10 not working

Tags: pdf, ifilter

I'm trying to use Adobe PDF Ifilter 11 on Win 10 to extract text from PDF files via a general Ifilter text extraction program in c#. The program contains the following code

```
private static NativeMethods.IFilter LoadFilterFromDll(string dllName, string filterPersistClass)
    {
        // Get a classFactory for our classID
        var classFactory = ComHelpers.GetClassFactory(dllName, filterPersistClass);
        if (classFactory == null)
            return null;

        // And create an IFilter instance using that class factory
        var filterGuid = new Guid("89BCB740-6119-101A-BCB7-00DD010655AF");
        Object ppunk;
        classFactory.CreateInstance(null, ref filterGuid, out ppunk);
        return (ppunk as NativeMethods.IFilter);
    }
```

Usiing the Adobe PDF IFlter 11 (and IFilter 9). The CreateInstance call is very slow to execute and when the text is extracted  is called the message

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

appears.

Text extraction works OK with the PDFLib TET Ifilter.

Adobe Reader DC is installed.

Does anyone know a workaround that would allow an Adobe PDF IFilter to be used?